# Looping through the page numbers with Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Attempting to update my script so that it searches through not only the url provided but all of the pages in range (1-3) and adds them to the CSV. Can anyone spot why my current code would not be working? The addition to pages following 1 are in the following format: `page-2`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
from csv import writer
from random import randint
from time import sleep

#example of second page url: https://www.propertypal.com/property-for-sale/ballymena-area/page-2

url= "https://www.propertypal.com/property-for-sale/ballymena-area/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

for page in range(1, 4):
    req = requests.get(url + 'page-' + str(page), headers=headers)
    # print(page)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
    lists = soup.find_all('li', class_="pp-property-box")

    with open('ballymena.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
        thewriter = writer(f)
        header = ['Address', 'Price']
        thewriter.writerow(header)

        for list in lists:
            title = list.find('h2').text
            price = list.find('p', class_="pp-property-price").text

            info = [title, price]
            thewriter.writerow(info)

sleep(randint(2,10))
```

Comment: It’s your indentation. You need all your code to be within your for page loop block

Comment: i've updated the question code snippet - but still having no joy. apologies if I'm being very rookie, Python is very new to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwrite req multiple times and end up only analyzing the results of page 2. Put everything inside your loop.
edit: Also the upper limit in `range()` is not included, so you probably want to do `for page in range(1, 4):` to get the first three pages.

edit full example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer


url = "https://www.propertypal.com/property-for-sale/ballymena-area/page-"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

with open('ballymena.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)
    header = ['Address', 'Price']
    thewriter.writerow(header)

    for page in range(1, 4):
        req = requests.get(f"{url}{page}", headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

        for li in soup.find_all('li', class_="pp-property-box"):
            title = li.find('h2').text
            price = li.find('p', class_="pp-property-price").text

            info = [title, price]
            thewriter.writerow(info)
```

Comment: i've updated the question code snippet - but still having no joy. apologies if I'm being very rookie, Python is very new to me!

Comment: Ah, you opening the file in write mode. Try to replace the w with a to append.
`with open('ballymena.csv', 'a', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:`

Comment: Or even better, first open the file, write your header. And then only append to it within your loop.

Comment: i've edited my post to share an example.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from bitflip is fine, however a few things I'll point out to help you.

1. try to avoid variable names that are predefined functions in python. For example `list` being one of those.
2. while csv writer is a fine package to use, also consider using pandas. You will likely further down the road need to do some data manipulation and what not, so might as well familiarise yourself with the package now. It's a very powerful tool.

Here's how I would have coded it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
import pandas as pd
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from os.path import exists

#example of second page url: https://www.propertypal.com/property-for-sale/ballymena-area/page-2

url= "https://www.propertypal.com/property-for-sale/ballymena-area/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

# Check if csv file exists
file_exists = exists('ballymena.csv')

for page in range(1, 4):
    rows = []
    req = requests.get(url + 'page-' + str(page), headers=headers)
    # print(page)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
    lists = soup.find_all('li', class_="pp-property-box")
    
    for li in lists:
        title = li.find('h2').text
        price = li.find('p', class_="pp-property-price").text
        
        row = {
            'Address':title,
            'Price':price}
        
        rows.append(row)
        
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    
    # If file doesnt exists, write initial file
    if not file_exists:
        df.to_csv('ballymena.csv', index=False)
        file_exists = True
        
    # If it already exists, ammend to file
    else:
        df.to_csv('ballymena.csv', mode = 'a', header = False, index = False)
        
    sleep(randint(2,10))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've seen a lot of chatter about pandas so this is really helpful. One question I have around this approach compared to using csv writer is that previously I could update my script to `amend` instead of `write` (to keep csv current) - is this a possibility with pandas? Trying to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: Yes you can amend with pandas' `.to_csv()`. Theres a few ways you can go about doing it. I'll update the code to show how you could achieve that

Comment: @cts, ok updated in the code. You can see that you can chnage the mode to `'a'`, and then tell it to not include the headers when ammending